# AWS EC2インスタンスへのSSHの方法

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

ssh先はIPv4パブリックIPとパブリック DNS (IPv4)のどちらを使うのが適切なのでしょうか?

AWSのドキュメント↓を見るとDNSのほうになってますが、IPアドレスでもsshはできました。
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

ひょっとしたら何か使い分けがあるのかもとも思っています。
詳しい方、ご教示ください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

どちらが適切と言うのは無いと思います。大抵の場合はどちらでも良く、場合によっては用途に応じて使い分ける感じかと。

例として思いつくのは、ドメイン名ベースのアクセス制御やルーティングを行いたい、といった場合に DNS を使う事になります。

また、DNS名を使う場合は、クライアントがDNSサーバーに対して、名前解決を行う事になりますので、そのオーバーヘッドを減らしたい場合はIPの方が良いと思います。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます。SSHではどちらでもよいということですね。DNSを使って説明されてるのは、HTTP/HTTPSでの例ということでしょうか？

Comment: 例として書いたのは、、HTTP/HTTPSもそうですが、sshd だと hosts.allowやaccess.confによるアクセス制限でホスト名ベースのルールが記述できます。他にはFirewallやRouterなどでホスト名ベースでIPルーティングの設定をするといった使い方があり、全般的な意味合いで書きました。